# VSTO Outlook AddIn: How to handle event when AppointmentItem.Body changes

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I tried to catch the event when the AppointmentItem.Body changes. Handling the PropertyChange on the AppointmentItem does not get called when I type in text or save the AppointmentItem. It gets called when I hit the button "Add Participants though".
Best would be to get the Keydown on the body editor?

Comment: Why do you need to track immediately what has been typed for the appointment body?

Comment: Because I need to enable / disable Ribbon immediately depending on the contents of the body (keywords)

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model may not propagate changes made in the Outlook UI until you switch focus to another field and/or save the item. This is a well-known issue when dealing with the Outlook object model.